# ng-selected first that is not hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a select list:

```
<option ng-repeat="hour in Hours" 
             value="{{hour.Value}}"
             ng-show="filterEvent($index)"
             ng-selected="hour.Value == EventDate || $first">
      {{hour.Text}}
</option>
```

And I want the first element that is not hidden to be automatically selected. Right now if I hide the first elements it wont change the selected index.

How can I do this?

Comment: what does filterEvent do ??

Comment: @Deep returns true or false if it passes the criteria

Answer (score 1):

just  hide the first option

```
<select ng-model="hour" required="required"
  ng-options="hour.value as hour for hour in hours" >
    <option style="display:none" value="">select a type</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can hide using ng-hide also

Answer (score 1):

Angular tends to ignore the selected atributte, if you want an element to be selected simply give your select a ng-model and set the value you want selected to your model variable.

```
<select ng-model="selectValue" name="mySelect">
    <option ng-repeat="hour in Hours" 
         value="{{hour.Value}}"
         ng-show="filterEvent($index)"
         >
  {{hour.Text}}
   </option>
</select>
```

And, in your controller use a forEach to find the first visible value of your array and asign it's value to your model variable.